# Excel formatting, removing the date from time formatting

Tags: excel, time, formatting

I am exporting agent call data from Cisco. The agent logged on time presents as 172:48:23 01/01/1900. How do I reformat the cells to time only, removing the date so that I can convert the time only to decimal time?

Comment: How is your time uploaded now, is it formatted as text or as time/date? I suspect the first, as excel would change the above example to `08/01/1900  04:48:23`. This cannot be fixed through formatting, and needs to be trimmed correctly with a formula or through VBA.

Comment: Can I use a formula in a new column to isolate the time?

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the date-time value from a text entry like in your example, there are various things that need to be done.

First of all the date `01/01/1900` is excels base date, basically the date version of "Zero". This part is unnecessary, as all the info you need is in your extended time part. This can be trimmed like so:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-11)
```

This formula will take the value in A1 (assuming this is where your text is) and count the number of characters. Then it will subtract 11 characters (the fixed length of your date including trailing space) and return that number of characters from your cell starting at the left, leaving you with "172:48:23".

However this is still not very useful as it is text and you won't be able to calculate with it. Therefore it can be converted to the number of days as so:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-11))
```

This will give you the amount of days within this time. (In your example, 7 days). The reason the date needs to be trimmed (and the time doesn't as per below) is because it will recognise "01/01" as a value of 1 instead, leading to incorrect results.

But this won't give us the time, so this needs to be added:

```
=TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

This will give you the time in hours, minutes and seconds from your time (in your example 4 hours, 48 minutes and 23 seconds.

To add this together, use:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-11))+TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

This will give you a full calculable date and time version of your number. In your example, represented by decimal time "7.200266204" which you can then set to any format you like. (For example, I chose custom format `dd "Days" hh:mm:ss` giving me "07 Days 04:48:23")